# Display rows where multiple columns are different

Tags: sql

I have data that looks like this. Thousands of rows returned, but this is just a sample.
Most days have the same numbers in them, but some do not. Note that ID 1 and 5 have identical numbers every day.

| ID | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 |
| 2 | 44 | 44 | 30 | 30 | 44 | 44 | 44 |
| 3 | 55 | 55 | 55 | 55 | 80 | 90 | 55 |
| 4 | 12 | 12 | 43 | 43 | 43 | 43 | 43 |
| 5 | 36 | 36 | 36 | 36 | 36 | 36 | 36 |

I'd like to only return rows where the days of the week have different numbers.

In this case, the only IDs returned should be 2, 3 & 4.

What would I want this query to look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Please TAG your RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea that should work in most RDBMS (with some syntax tweaks) is the following.
This is SQL Server compatible: pivot the days into rows and count the distinct values and filter accordingly:

```
select id
from t
cross apply (
    select Count(distinct d) from (
    values(sunday),(monday),(tuesday),(wednesday),(thursday),(friday),(saturday)
    )d(d)
)d(v)
where d.v>1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!

I see the distinct d and then following the days you have  the following:
        )d(d)
)d(v)
where d.v>1

Can you explain that to me like I'm 7?

Comment: It's simply )`d` is the *alias* for the sub-query and `(d)` is the name of the column it returns (the single column of values) - d for *day*, you could spell it out I was just lazy lol; same for `)d(v)`, the alias for the *cross apply* followed by the name of the column it returns - therefore d (the alias) . v (the column)

Comment: The column(v) was the only part I hadn't guessed at.
Makes sense when you say it out loud though.

Thanks!!